# JFormDesigner 8 Editor in Eclipse does not show any Tooltips

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, editor, jform-designer

No matter, what I do, JForm Designer 8 Editor shows no tooltips, for one exception (see below)
I searched with different terms and stuff, but I can't find anything about this issue.
Mostly I then find stuff about Tooltips for GUI generated with JFormDesigner, but for the JFormDesigner itself.

I tried 8.1.1 and 8.2.1 - both show no tooltips. Version 7.0.4 does, but complains about not beeing compatible with Java 17, but I guess I still will go back to v7 for now, as I don't see anything not working, except it shows this warning all the time.

One weird thing: I shortly could see the tooltips again, when hovering above buttons with the mouse, when using JForm Designer 8.2.1 and creating a new .jdf file in any project.
Suddenly it worked in all .jdf files, everywhere tooltips again. Could even close the new.jdf Editor, but in the moment, I deleted the file, all tooltips where gone again.
In v8 the tooltips look different, they have a rounded white rectangle instead if the standard yellow one.

Sadly, I wanted to know if this works for 8.1.1 too, so I downgraded, and now I cannot reproduce this behaviour again, no matter what I try (fresh installation, upgrading from v7, etc.)
I though, ok then, I'll simply put some unused new .jfd in a local unimportant project and done, but sadly it was just this one chance.

Any ideas, how I could get them working in JFormDesigner v8? Thanks!